# CSS Div does not want to show up whatever i do

Tags: html, css

I have got a simple part of a website where i am using some CSS to get a square tile. The problem is the whole tile is never actually showing up, when i use it in HTML and put a lot of text in it, the width and height attribute dont seem to have any effect on the div. Here

`

```css
.tileYellowDouble {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: Black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
#imageTile {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(Thimo.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
body {
  background: url(York.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.main {
  position: fixed;
  border: solid 1px black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -300px;
  margin-left: -500px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #35bc7a;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="imageTile"></div>
  <div class="tileYellowDouble">Doesnt show the background color or border</div>
</div>
```

I just found out that when i comment out .main it does show the box, but when it is back in it just shows a clear background. Also using Z-index doesnt work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ttfkg8ax/ The black square does show, what is the problem?

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little. Making your text black and your background black is a little mind-boggling. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0L4zzm46/) what you're after?

Comment: the div and text are showing, but everything is black so you just can't see it (select the text, that should make it visible) - not sure what you're after though

Comment: This is really strange, this code is also on my website: http://ttv-boomgaardshoek.nl/About/index.php and there it doesnt show up. what is wrong

Comment: Except it is showing your background color and borders. Nice suit btw.

Comment: Thanks xD But why is the tile part not showing on the website but it is showing it in the snippet thing on here?

Comment: Your margin values are not correct, what you're going to do with the tile?

Comment: Im just going to show some text and make the div clickable

Comment: @ThimoFranken You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Lmarc3zk/